# Variable is possibly undefined with Svelte "bind:this={}"

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte

When I try to use Svelte's `bind:this` attribute, I get this shown in vscode:

```
'cardGroup' is possibly 'undefined'.js(18048)
```

And when run, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'childNodes')
```

I was originally working in Typescript where I got the error that the bound variable was not declared before usage.

Script:

```js
    let cardGroup;
    let cardContainers = cardGroup.childNodes;
    console.log(cardContainers.length);
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="cardGroup" bind:this={cardGroup}>
    [content]
</div>
```

It is entirely possible that I'm missing something but I haven't found anything using this binding that isnt doing exactly what I am, from what I can tell.

Comment: You can also create and use your own [action](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-action) to achieve this. That will work even when your element is in `{#if}` or `{#each}`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the issue. In order to use the `bind:this` for Svelte, you need to use the onMount function to assign it.

Here's my working solution (back to Typescript)

```
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    let cardGroup: HTMLDivElement;
    let cardContainers: NodeListOf<ChildNode>;
    onMount(() => {
        cardContainers = cardGroup.childNodes;
        console.log(cardContainers.length);
    });
```

Comment: In the next version of Svelte (5 coming soon) this will not work anymore. https://svelte-5-preview.vercel.app/docs/breaking-changes#components-are-no-longer-classes-bind-this-changes

Comment: What will be the option instead?

Comment: Most of the time you do not need to access the dom yourself. Svelte can do without. But in Svelte we have "use:action" which gives you the node and ...
See this example: https://svelte.dev/repl/f27d278f08a1437ba46c3a7f71b3e36d?version=3.20.1

Comment: I think bind:this is in a way back in Svelte-5 (runes svelte@5.0.0-next.66). Wrap the component in a div and you get the dom: See this example in the commit: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/pull/10598/commits/9a488d56f8604b315bdea83df95be58508217c76#diff-440e0712e71c810aa3f1008a70c4c012ee65c5f4363b18389812520524114199